# Want to get Timezone using jquery

Tags: javascript

In jquery,

```
var date = new Date();
```

It is taking system Date Not site Time zone

```
var date = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
```

it is also not working.please anyone help for this.thank you.

Comment: It's supposed to use the system time zone. What other time zone would it use?

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this? This is just plain Javascript, there are no date functions in jQuery.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client machine, it doesn't know anything about the server. If you want the server time, get the date in a PHP script on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Return the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time:

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

> The result n will be:
>   -300
>
> The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time difference between UTC time and local time, in minutes.

For example, If your time zone is GMT+2, -120 will be returned.

Note: The returned value is not a constant, because of the practice of using Daylight Saving Time.

Tip: The Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is the time set by the World Time Standard.

Note: UTC time is the same as GMT time.

Comment: difference between UTC and Local Time in jquery

Comment: He's already doing this in `var date = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();` The only difference is that you use two variables instead of a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has only one date/time function, which is `$.now()`

If you meant JavaScript, the answer is still no. You can only obtain a time zone offset from `date.getTimezoneOffset()`. You can't get a time zone - at least not in all browsers.

You can guess at the time zone, by using the jsTimeZoneDetect library, but it is just a guess. It may or may not be accurate.

If you can guarantee your users are running a browser that supports the brand new ECMAScript Internationalization API, you can get the user's time zone with:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```